# Angular request to Spring Gateway No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, cors, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Angular application which is trying to send a GET request to a microservice via a Spring Gateway application.

I have configured allowed origin on the microservice (helloworld) to allow from localhost:4200. If I configure the angular application to use helloworld direct url, the request is successful and I get the response I am expecting.

I have configured my Spring Gateway application to provide and path to talk to the helloworld application using itself as the go between. This works via the browser and I get the same successful response as before.

However, when I configure the Angular application to go via the Spring Gateway application... I get an error in the browser when the Angular application tries to contact via Spring Gateway:

**from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

So it is the gateway rejecting the request and it never gets to the hello world application. Here is the yaml configuration for the gateway application:

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
      '[/**]':
          allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:4200"
          allowedMethods: 
          - POST
          - GET
          - OPTIONS
          allowCredentials: true
              

              
      routes:
      - id: hello
        uri: lb://helloworld
        predicates:
        - Path=/hello/*

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Here is my typescript basic call to the gateway service:

```
this.httpClient.get<string>('http://localhost:8080/hello/hi')
    .subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I am as you can see using eureka to resolve the application but this works as tested from the browser. Any help would be much appreciated.

===EDIT===
The below configuration ensuring there is not Spring security dependency resolves the issue:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      default-filters:
      - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
              allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:4200"
              allowedMethods: 
              - POST
              - GET
              - OPTIONS
              allowedHeaders: "*"
              allowCredentials: true

              
      routes:
#      - id: auth
#        uri: lb://java-api-workflow-auth
#        predicates:
#        - Path=/java-api-workflow-auth/*
      - id: hello
        uri: lb://helloworld
        predicates:
        - Path=/hello/*
```

Comment: Hi is that you issue is resolved ..as i have the same issue now ...

Comment: same problem..have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The below configuration ensuring there is not Spring security dependency resolves the issue:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      default-filters:
      - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
              allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:4200"
              allowedMethods: 
              - POST
              - GET
              - OPTIONS
              allowedHeaders: "*"
              allowCredentials: true

              
      routes:
#      - id: auth
#        uri: lb://java-api-workflow-auth
#        predicates:
#        - Path=/java-api-workflow-auth/*
      - id: hello
        uri: lb://helloworld
        predicates:
        - Path=/hello/*
```